# React pass data if true or false

Tags: reactjs

Why is it it always true (Icon) even though the `name: Teacher` is false? did i miss something?

I just want that if the `PERMISSIONS_GROUPING` the withIcon is `false` the withIcon will not display, I dont know why the withIcon say always true

```
export const PERMISSIONS_GROUPING = [
  {
    name: 'Teacher',
    withIcon: false
  },
  {
    name: 'new',
    withIcon: true
  }
];



import { PERMISSIONS_GROUPING } from '../role.util';

const propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  withIcon: PropTypes.bool
};

const defaultProps = {
  name: '',
  withIcon: true
};

const RolePermissionRow = ({
  name,
  withIcon
}) => {
   return (
     {PERMISSIONS_GROUPING.map(item =>  
      {item.withIcon ? (
        <IconButton
          size="small"
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(!open);
            setDisablePermission(
              !open ? disablePermission + 1 : disablePermission - 1
            );
          }}
          className={open ? 'collapse' : 'expand'}
        >
          {open ? (
            <RemoveIcon fontSize="7px" />
          ) : (
            <AddIcon fontSize="7px" />
          )}
        </IconButton>
      ) : <IconButton size="small" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }} />
      }
       )}
      {name} 

  )
 }
```

I've tried to console the item.withIcon the result is fine,

```
false
true
```

but i dont know why even when the data is true, no Icon display

Comment: Did you pass `withIcon` prop like this? `<RolePermissionRow withIcon={withIcon} />`? How did you pass the prop?Show the code

Comment: Yes, but I dont know why it is always `true`

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please try console loggin withIcon in the component and let us know what you get?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta, can you please check my question again? i updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove defaultProps and render RolePermissionRow like below.

```
<List>
    {PERMISSIONS_GROUPING.map(item => <RolePermissionRow name={item.name} withIcon={item.withIcon}>)}
</List>
```

Comment: How to implement it with my existing code?

Comment: can you please see my updated question?